# Absurd result in inequality

Tags: inequality

I have this inequality

$(x-2)^2 \ge 0 $

So I solve it like this

$(x-2)^2 \ge 0 \implies (x-2)(x-2)\ge0$

$\implies x(x-2)-2(x-2)\ge0 \implies x(x-2)\ge2(x-2)\implies x\ge2$

But obviously $x\ge2$ is false in R

What did I miss?

Comment: $x-2$ can be negative.

Comment: You divided both sides by $x-2$... What happens if $x-2$ was equal to zero?  You just divided both sides by zero.  You can't do that.  What if $x-2$ is positive?  Well... that is fine, you had the right outcome.  What if $x-2$ was negative?  Well... the sign should have flipped.

Comment: "*I have this inequality: $(x-2)^2\geq 0$*"  You should know that a real number squared is *always* greater than or equal to zero... so *every* $x$ satisfies $(x-2)^2\geq 0$

Comment: Thank you I got it!

Comment: You divide by (x-2); If (x-2)>0, then you get x>2. Division by (x-2)<0 (negative, the > changes into <) you get x<2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn’t have divided both sides by $x-2$ As it can be negative.
$$-1>-2 \not \Rightarrow 1>2$$

Comment: "*You couldn't have divided...*"  Yes, you could... but in doing so you need to split into cases based on the sign of $x-2$ and considered each case separately.

Comment: Yes, maybe “you couldn’t have just have divided” would have fitted better.

Answer (score 0):

In your last step you divide both sides of the inequality by $(x-2)$ which is negative for $x < 2$, and this would require reversing the inequality sign.  Instead you could simply split your solution into two cases: $x\geq 2$ and $x< 2$, and derive the entire solution space by considering each case individually.